# Fedora Media Writer runs from disk but not from USB

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, fedora

I have a Windows 10 machine and want to install Fedora 25 as a dual boot operating system.

After downloading Fedora Media Writer for Fedora 25 onto my Windows 10 machine, I tried to copy it to a USB drive and run the program (as advised in [installation instructions](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/)) but it did not start.

Then, I tried to run the program from my `C:\` on Windows 10 and it started.

Is it OK to continue running this way from `C:\` and install Fedora?

On searching online for this problem some posts suggest using the code at [this github repository](https://github.com/MartinBriza/MediaWriter/issues/21) to fix the problem but I am not sure if this is a valid solution and if the author of this code is one of the Fedora developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

Fedora Media Writer is a tool to create a bootable USB stick that you can use to install Fedora; it should be run from your Windows install, as its purpose is to populate the USB stick with the actual Fedora live installer.

### In-depth

To install Fedora, a live "disk" (which can be any storage medium, such as  a USB drive) containing the operating system is booted from, which then allows you to install the operating system contained on that disk onto the computer's physical hard drive, where it is persistent.

This live disk has to first be created from a disk image (a file containing the contents of a storage device), which is where Fedora Media Writer comes into play; it is a utility to write a live system image to a disk (the USB drive). Running from a host OS (in this case Windows, though it could be any OS) it copies the system image onto the disk, but the tool itself is not the image that gets copied; Media Writer simply does the copying.

The Media Writer tool *must* be run from somewhere other than the flash drive (in this case, `C:\`) because otherwise, when it tries to write to the USB drive, it would overwrite itself on the disk. Think of Media Writer  as a utility with which to prepare the disk, not image contents of the disk itself.